# Why the red line in histogram is too short?

Tags: r

```
  test <- NULL
  for(i in 1:1000){
   p <- rgamma(1,239,10)
   yrep <- rpois (10,p)
   test <- c(test,yrep)}
 hist (test, xlab="T (yrep)", yaxt="n", cex=1,col = "yellow")
 lines(rep(22,2), col="red", c(0,100))
 print(mean(test<=22))
```

I got
[image]

But why the red line cannot exceed the histogram? How to edit my code to let the red line be normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `abline` instead:

```
 test <- NULL
  for(i in 1:1000){
   p <- rgamma(1,239,10)
   yrep <- rpois (10,p)
   test <- c(test,yrep)}
 hist (test, xlab="T (yrep)", yaxt="n", cex=1,col = "yellow")
 abline(v=22, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Vincent's answer fixes the problem using `abline`. But if you need to know how high to go (perhaps you don't want a full-vertical line), then here's "why":

First, `hist(.)` returns a list that includes some meta about the histogram.

```r
set.seed(42)
# test <- ...

h <-  hist (test, xlab="T (yrep)", yaxt="n", cex=1,col = "yellow")
str(h)
# List of 6
#  $ breaks  : int [1:20] 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 ...
#  $ counts  : int [1:19] 18 70 191 405 812 1154 1554 1545 1358 1084 ...
#  $ density : num [1:19] 0.0009 0.0035 0.00955 0.02025 0.0406 ...
#  $ mids    : num [1:19] 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 ...
#  $ xname   : chr "test"
#  $ equidist: logi TRUE
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

The y-axis is defined off of the `$counts` variable, so we can see that it goes up to at least 1554.

Another way to see what the axis is doing is with

```r
par("usr")
# [1]    6.48   47.52  -62.16 1616.16
```

This tells us that the x-axis ranges from 6.48 to 47.52, and the y-axis ranges from -62.16 to 1616.16. (The reason `y` includes negative values is that by default, R expands the plot by 4% in both directions.) From this, you could know that your `line` would need to span from `0` (or `-62.16` if you wanted to start at the true bottom) to `1616.16` (or around up). This says that our look at `h$counts` would have ended near the top of the hist bars but not at the top of the plotted region.